# Navigation drawer alignment issue

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I made navigation drawer under action bar. It's working fine on Jellybean os but in  marshmallow os it's not working..

[image: in maeshamllow]

in jellybean
[image]
my activity main xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_checkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fdfdfd"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by this way

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.qproinnovations.schoolmanagement.activity.HomeActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A drawer layout is allowed only 2 children, the first is a main content view, the second is the drawer. You need to combine your first two views into a linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_checkout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you implement the suggested change?

Comment: yea.when I implemented this.No change in output.In marshmallow the naviagtion drawer is not under the action bar..thanks

Comment: So you want it under the action bar? Suggested solution puts it on top of action bar.

To put it below action bar you need to define a linear layout whose first child will be action bar and second child will be drawerlayout. And you need to remove app_bar_checkout element from within Drawerlayout